# Find the sum $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n^2}{3^n}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis, power-series, geometric-series

This problem comes from [UChicago's Math Subject GRE Practice Problems](https://math.uchicago.edu/%7Emin/GRE/files/week1.pdf). Specifically week 1, problem 6:

Evaluate the sum $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n^2}{3^n}$.

The answer says "Use the standard trick." Any idea what they mean? I know the sum of a geometric series, but I'm not sure what to do here given the $n^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, we use concept of convergence of power series.
for $|x|<1$,

$\sum{x^n}= \frac{x}{1-x}$
Since ,Rad of convergence of power series is 1 ,we can differentiate term by term in its interval of convergence

$\sum{nx^{n-1}}$ = $\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}$

$\sum{nx^n}=\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}$

Again differentiating,
$\sum{n^2x^{n-1}}=\frac{1+x}{(1-x)^3}$

$\sum{n^2x^n}=\frac{x^2+x}{(1-x)^3}$

Since, $x=1/3$ lies in interval of convergence
We get,
$\sum\frac{n^2}{3^n}=\frac{\frac{1}{9}+\frac{1}{3}}{\frac{2^3}{3^3}}$
$=\frac{3}{2}$

Comment: OHHH, see I was struggling because n(n-1) seemed ugly, but multiplying by x on both sides of the equation makes things nice again, duh. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Another form of the trick is
$$n^2 x^n=n(n-1) x^n+n x^n= x^2\big[n(n-1)x^{n-2}\big]+x \big[n x^{n-1}\big]$$ that is to say
$$n^2 x^n=x^2 (x^n)''+x(x^n)'$$

Answer (score 0):

You need to realize that this series is the value of the power series $\sum_{n \geq 1} n^2x^n$ evaluated $x = 1/3$, and this power series can be computed as a rational function of $x$ on its interval or disc of convergence by repeated differentiation starting from the geometric series
$$
\sum_{n \geq 1} x^n = \frac{x}{1-x}
$$
for $|x| < 1$.  More precisely, apply $d/dx$ to both sides of that equation, then multiply by $x$, do those again, and then set $x = 1/3$.

You are expected to realize immediately that coefficient factors of $n$ get introduced in power series by differentiating and then multiplying by $x$:
$$
x\frac{d}{dx}\sum_{n \geq 0} a_nx^n = \sum_{n \geq 0} na_nx^n = \sum_{n \geq 1} na_nx^n.
$$
So for each positive integer $k$,
$$
\left(x\frac{d}{dx}\right)^k\sum_{n \geq 0} a_nx^n = \sum_{n \geq 1} n^ka_nx^n.
$$

**Remark**.  Differentiating twice without multiplying by $x$ between the two derivatives will not lead directly to the desired answer, but it can be made to work by remembering prior calculations. When $|x| < 1$,
$$
\sum_{n \geq 1} x^n = \frac{x}{1-x} \Longrightarrow 
\sum_{n \geq 1} nx^{n-1} = \frac{1}{(1-x)^2}
$$
by taking derivatives of both sides.  Then taking derivatives again,
$$
\sum_{n \geq 1} n(n-1)x^{n-2} = \frac{2}{(1-x)^3},
$$
so
$$
\sum_{n \geq 1} n^2x^{n-2} = \frac{2}{(1-x)^3} + \sum_{n \geq 1} nx^{n-2}.
$$
Now multiply both sides by $x^2$ and recall the earlier formula for $\sum_{n \geq 1} nx^{n-1}$:
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n \geq 1} n^2x^{n} & = \frac{2x^2}{(1-x)^3} + x\sum_{n \geq 1} nx^{n-1} \\ & = \frac{2x^2}{(1-x)^3} + \frac{x}{(1-x)^2}.
\end{align*}
Now set $x = 1/3$:
$$
\sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{n^2}{3^n} = \frac{2/9}{8/27} + \frac{1/3}{4/9} =  \frac{3}{4} + \frac{3}{4} = \frac{3}{2}.
$$

Comment: I considered this, but it gets a little messy because you then have n(n-1), but I'll try that and get back to you.

Comment: That is because you are *not* doing what I said: you're just differentiating twice.  You need to use $d/dx$, *then* multiply by $x$, and then do those in succession again.  Do not just differentiate twice, since that will lead to the mess with $n(n-1)$ that you wrote about.

Comment: That's what I just realized. Thank you so much; that's where I was messing up!

Comment: I added a remark at the end to show how you could solve the problem without too much trouble by differentiating twice without an intermediate "multiply by $x$" step, and instead only multiply by a power of $x$ at the end to make the exponents of $x$ match up with the desired expression at $x = 1/3$.

Comment: Thank you for the elaboration! That combination of equations was what I wasn't hesitant to avoid, but thank you for writing it out, and definitely that is a valid route!